# VBA Class : Collection.item member is a collection . How to retrieve sub collection item elements

Tags: vba, class, collections

I have this template data

Header of file ((string1, string2...)
group1 header (string1, string2...)
group1/line1 (string1, string2...)
group1/line2 (string1, string2...)
group2 header (string1, string2...)
group2/line1 (string1, string2...)
group2/line2 (string1, string2...)

Note : The datas belonging to group header and group line are different type even if they are on the same 'coloumn' (raw data comes from text file)

I create my main class (populate collection) and data class (populate item : cData_Nomination), everything works individualy BUT I need to create :

-1 file collection (I have multiples files) which store 
-- fields (file header) and 
-- x sub collection (groups) wich store
--- fields (group header)
--- x sub collection which store
---- fields (line data)

In the folowing code on line 170 .oDpo is the group collection every data are store on a collection with property Let (....).
Everything seem to be store !

```
Public Function NomCreate(m_sFilepath As String, m_objDataList() As String, m_clDpo As Collection) As cData_Nomination

10        On Error GoTo Err_Handler
          Dim Functions As New cFunctions
          Dim objResult As cData_Nomination
          Dim objDate() As String



      'Note : Init Var(s) /Object(s)
      '----------------------------

20        Set objResult = New cData_Nomination

30        With objResult
40            .FileName = Functions.String_NZ(m_sFilepath)
50            .DataSource = Functions.String_NZ(m_objDataList(1))
60            .DelRes = Functions.String_NZ(m_objDataList(2))
70            .DateTime = Functions.Date_NZ(m_objDataList(4) & " " & m_objDataList(5) & ":00")
80            objDate = Split(Replace(m_objDataList(6), " - ", "-"), "-")
90            .DateTimeRange_Start = Functions.Date_NZ(objDate(0))
100           .DateTimeRange_End = Functions.Date_NZ(objDate(1))
110           .Sender = Functions.String_NZ(m_objDataList(7))
120           .Receiver = Functions.String_NZ(m_objDataList(8))
130           .GasPointName = Functions.String_NZ(m_objDataList(9))
140           .GasPointNameExternal = Functions.String_NZ(m_objDataList(10))
150           .Description = Functions.String_NZ(m_objDataList(11))
160           .DataType = Functions.String_NZ(m_objDataList(12))
170           .oDpo = Dpo
180       End With

Err_Exit:
          'Note : Return Function value
190       Set NomCreate = objResult
          'Note : Delete object
200       Set objResult = Nothing
          'Note : Exit
210       Exit Function

Err_Handler:
          'Note : Exit Function
220       GoTo Err_Exit
```

When I try to read data i got a problem I can't access to the collection .oDo via property Get (see the following code)

```
'property belonging to class cData_Nomination
Public Property Let oDpo(ByVal oCollection As Collection)
    Dim m_oDpo As New Collection
    Set m_oDpo = oCollection
End Property
```

How can I pass collection to an existing item collection (I might have been wrong) and How can i retrieve my sub collection items from the main collection ?

I hope it's clear ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Class cNum (Extract of parent)**

```
Private m_sFileName As String
Private oDpo As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set oDpo = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get FileName() As String
    FileName = m_sFileName    
End Property

Public Property Let FileName(ByVal sFileName As String)
    m_sFileName = sFileName    
End Property

Public Property Get Dpo() As Collection
    Set Dpo = oDpo    
End Property

Public Property Set DpoAdd(DpoCollection As Collection)
    Dim DpoItem    
    For Each DpoItem In DpoCollection    
        oDpo.Add DpoItem        
    Next    
End Property
```

Class cDop (Child of parent)

```
Private m_sDelivery As String
Private oQty As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set oQty = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get Delivery() As String
    Delivery = m_sDelivery
End Property

Public Property Let Delivery(ByVal sDelivery As String)
    m_sDelivery = sDelivery
End Property


Public Property Get Qty() As Collection
    Set Qty = oQty
End Property

Public Property Set QtyAdd(QtyCollection As Collection)
    Dim QtyItem    
    For Each QtyItem In QtyCollection
        oQty.Add QtyItem
    Next
End Property
```

**Class cQty (Sub Child)**

```
Private m_sStatus As String

Public Property Get Status() As String
    Status = m_sStatus
End Property

Public Property Let Status(ByVal sStatus As String)
    m_sStatus = sStatus
End Property
```

**Regular Module**

```
Sub myModule()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim cNum As cNum
    Dim cDpo As cDpo
    Dim cQty As cQty
    Dim oNum As Collection
    Dim oDpo As Collection
    Dim oQty As Collection

    Set oNum = New Collection
    For i = 1 To 3
        Set cNum = New cNum
        cNum.FileName = "File " & i

        Set oDpo = New Collection
        For j = 1 To 3
            Set cDpo = New cDpo
            cDpo.Qty = "Qty" & i & j
            cDpo.Delivery = "Delivery " & i & j

            Set oQty = New Collection

            For k = 1 To 3
                Set cQty = New cQty
                cQty.Statut = "OK_" & i & "-" & j & "-" & k
                oQty.Add cQty                
            Next k

            Set cDpo.QtyAdd = oQty        

            oDpo.Add cDpo

        Next j

        Set cNum.DpoAdd = oDpo
        oNum.Add cNum

    Next i

    'Set oDpo = Nothing
    '

    For Each cNum In oNum
        Debug.Print ""
        Debug.Print "---------FILE ----------------"
        Debug.Print ""
        Debug.Print "-[NUM] " & cNum.FileName & " | " & cNum.Info
        Set oDpo = cNum.Dpo
        For Each cDpo In oDpo
            Debug.Print "--[DPO] " & cDpo.Counterpart & " | " & cDpo.Delivery

            Set oQty = cDpo.Qty
            For Each cQty In oQty
                Debug.Print "---[QTY] " & cQty.Quantity & " | " & cQty.Statut
            Next
        Next

    Next

End Sub
```